# Model data missing after ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

In https://github.com/jimshowalter/vocabutron/blob/master/src/app/settings/settings.component.html, the application starts with just the settings button displayed. Click the button, and the button disappears, replaced by the settings editor. Edit a setting and submit, you can see it getting pushed to the settings service. Submitting also makes the component disappear, and brings back the settings button. But the second time the settings button is clicked, the setting is missing. And the console log shows no activity from the settings component at all. It seems to be dead. Yet, adding a value for the setting and submitting it, the component turns out to still be there (as shown in the console).

Why doesn't redisplaying the component populate the editor with existing data?

```
import { Component, OnInit, isDevMode } from "@angular/core";
import { SettingsService } from "../settings.service";
import { Settings } from "../settings";

@Component({
  selector: "app-settings",
  templateUrl: "./settings.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./settings.component.css"]
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  model: Settings = null;
  display: boolean = false;

  constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService) {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsComponent.constructed");
    }
  }

  private updateSettings() {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsComponent.updateSettings");
    }
    this.model = this.settingsService.get();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsComponent.ngOnInit");
    }
    this.settingsService.changedMessage.subscribe(changed =>
      this.updateSettings()
    );
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    let result = this.settingsService.put(this.model);
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsComponent.onSubmit: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    }
    this.display = false;
  }
}

<div *ngIf=!display class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="display=true">Settings</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf=display class="container">
  <h2>Settings</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(); settingsForm.reset()" #settingsForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="settings" [(ngModel)]="model.maxWords" required pattern="([1-9]+[0-9]*)+"
        name="settings" #settingsModel="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="settingsModel.valid || settingsModel.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      Max words is required and must be a number from 1-N.
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!settingsForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

export class Settings {
  maxWords: number = 3;
}

import { Injectable, isDevMode } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { Settings } from "./settings";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SettingsService {
  changedMessageSource = new BehaviorSubject("changed");
  changedMessage = this.changedMessageSource.asObservable();

  private settings: Settings = new Settings();

  constructor() {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsService constructed");
    }
  }

  get(): Settings {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsService.get");
    }
    return this.settings;
  }

  changed() {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsService.changed");
    }
    this.changedMessageSource.next("changed");
  }

  put(settings: Settings): Settings {
    this.settings = settings;
    this.changed();
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log("SettingsService.put: " + JSON.stringify(this.settings));
    }
    return this.settings;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code, not a link to it. If that link dies in the future, this question will be completely ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that you are resetting the form by calling `reset()` in the form submit handler, but since the form is only being hidden and re-shown with *ngIf, there is no stage in which the model gets updated. The subject is not fired and update is not called as a result. Simply remove reset to fix.

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();" #settingsForm="ngForm">
```

There are few problems with this style of coding such as convoluted reasoning, as shown above, and non-performant change detection but those are concepts to be left for another day I think. For now, `BehaviorSubject` can directly emit changes to objects. Subscribing directly to this nets us the new settings in one step.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.settingsService.settings$.subscribe(settings =>
     this.model = settings;
  );
}

export class SettingsService {
  private settings: Settings = new Settings();

  private settingsSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.settings);
  settings$ = this.settingsSource.asObservable();

  ...

  changed() {
    this.settingsSubject.next(this.settings);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If you can point me to an example of a better way to do this, I'd appreciate it.